# Oracle SQL to shorten string in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to automate API load and facing field restriction. Basically I need to shorten string if its more than 24 characters.

I am considering logic to take the first 4 characters of the word and replace space with _. A number of words in the field are dynamic.

e.g. Corporate Responsibility = copr_resp

E.g. Social Distancing Criteria = soci_dist_crit

**Table_a**

ColA
Corporate Responsibility
Social Distancing Criteria

**Expected Result:**

Select ColA,  as Output from table_a;

Output
ColA                         Output
Corporate Responsibility     copr_resp
Social Distancing Criteria   soci_dist_crit

I prefer to do this using SQL. Any suggestion?

Comment: what is the max length of the expected output strings if you have a field restriction?

Comment: 24 characters max.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can divide the string into row and concat again as follows:

```
Select t.your_col,
       listagg( substr(regexp_substr(t.your_col,
                                    '[^ ]+', 1, levels.column_value), 
                       1, 4), 
              '_') within group (order by levels.column_value) as short_str
from your_table t
Cross join table(cast(multiset(select level from dual 
                 connect by level <= length (regexp_replace(t.your_col, '[^ ]+'))  + 1) 
                  as sys.OdciNumberList)) levels
Group by t.your_col
```

Comment: almost there. I know I didnt mention it in original question. But is it possible to remove special character like & and - completely?
Following gives output of : Lice_&_Lega_Resp, it will be nice to have lice_lega_resp

Comment: Select t.sub_division,
       listagg( substr(regexp_substr(t.sub_division,
                                    '[^ ]+', 1, levels.column_value), 
                       1, 4), 
              '_') within group (order by levels.column_value) as short_str
from (SELECT
'Licensing & Legal Responsibility' sub_division
FROM
    dual) t
Cross join table(cast(multiset(select level from dual 
                 connect by level <= length (regexp_replace(t.sub_division, '[^ ]+'))  + 1) 
                  as sys.OdciNumberList)) levels
Group by t.sub_division;